# Override css using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jquery can td width be overwritten as shown

```
<table>
<tr>
<td width="30%"></td>
<td width="70%" id="description"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
 $("#description").css({"width":"30%"})
</script>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid (missing `<tr>`) and you don't have an id set on the table cell for the jQuery code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your jQUery code inside document ready event.

```
$(function(){
     $("#description").removeAttr("width").css({"width":"30%"});
});
```

width should be set inside style and not as an attribute. First remove the attribute and then set the style. If you can use a class then it will be the best approach.

```
.elwidth
{
    width: 30%;
}

 $(function(){
         $("#description").removeAttr("width").addClass("elwidth");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="firstCell" width="30%">...</td>
    <td id="secondCell" width="70%">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $("#firstCell").attr("width", "40%");
  $("#secondCell").attr("width", "60%");
</script>
```

Although you shouldn't be using `width` attributes, rather use CSS properties to set the widths of table cells.